# Phonegap Jquery Animate stuck on movement

Tags: jquery, cordova

I've been creating a PhoneGap app and have been stuck on a problem creating this app. Majority of the div's on the app will have text that a user will input, this posed a problem since i wanted to maintain the font size and etc...

So basically i went on to create a jquery that moved my text within the div right and then left when it reached to the end of the content.

You can see the demo at

http://codepen.io/nike121/pen/xigpd

```
        var vx = 2; //handles speed on x axis

        function hitLR(el, bounding) {
            if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && vx < 0) {
                console.log('LEFT');
                vx = -1 * vx; //use the speed and -1 to move content to left
            }
            if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
                console.log('RIGHT');
                vx = -1 * vx;
            }
        }

        function mover(el, bounding) {
            hitLR(el, bounding);
            el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + vx + 'px';
            //el.style.top = el.offsetTop + vy + 'px';
            setTimeout(function() {
                mover(el, bounding);
            }, 100);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            mover($('.bouncer')[0], $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
        }, 250);

        $(".bouncyHouse").hover(function(){
             $( this ).css( "background","green" );
         });
```

Does anyone know how i can stop that annoying loop

Thanks a million

Comment: You probably have to rethink the logic in your `hitLR` function. It's getting stuck on the bouncy animation because it hits the border and moves left but this gives it space to move right again. What you could do is split the movement into different functions - one for left and one for right - and call the one that matches the situation.

Comment: makes sense! i'll try the fix - do you reckon this is the best way to achieve this? or should i be looking at another method?

Comment: It probably isn't the best method, but I can't think of another off the top of my head just yet. I'll post an answer with a fiddle if anything comes to mind!